# What is the most efficient way to compare dates in java

Tags: java, performance, date, comparison, compare

I want to compare dates in a loop which iterate through large number of objects. Comparison of the dates cost me a lot of time. What is the most efficient way to compare dates to improve the performance. Java has some date comparison methods like before,after or comparing using timestamps or using methods like compareTo(). Which one is the best ?

Comment: What have you tried? For what version of Java? For what operating system? Why do you think this *costs you a lot of time*?

Comment: What formats are your dates in? Are they strings? If so I can understand how parsing them into `Date` objects or comparing them character by character could be time-consuming. Consider storing them in epoch-milli format. Comparing two numbers is one of the fastest possible operations.

Comment: I'm using Java 6. I'm trying to filter the objects which are in certain date region. Dates are in the format of java.util.Date.

Comment: How do you compare the dates? Date.compareTo() should be really efficient.